# Cannot access member of a class through object reference

Tags: c#, reflection

The following code executes without error and prints "*In some*", which means that the statement

```
m[0].Invoke(o, args);
```

invokes the function `some` which is a member of the `foo` class, on object `o` and affects its public variable `i`. But when we uncomment the last line of the code and try to compile it, it produces an error. Why??

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class foo
{
    public int i;
    public foo(int ii = 0)
    {
        i = ii;
    }
    public void some(int ii)
    {
        i = ii;
        Console.WriteLine("In some ");
    }
}

class main
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        foo f = new foo();
        object o = new foo();

        Type t = typeof(foo);


        object[] args = new object[1];
        args[0] = 9;
        MethodInfo[] m = t.GetMethods();
        m[0].Invoke(o, args);
        //Console.WriteLine(o.i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when we uncomment the last line of the code and try to compile it, it produces an error. Why??

Because you've declared `o` as `System.Object`, which doesn't have a variable `i` defined on it as far as the compiler is concerned.  You'd need to either cast it to the known type, or use reflection to retrieve this value.

For example:

```
// You can cast here, since you know the type
foo oAsFoo = o as foo;
Console.WriteLine(oAsFoo.i);
```

Alternatively, use reflection to get the value:

```
FieldInfo field = t.GetField("i");
Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(o));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the `o` too `foo` in order to execute it.

```
Console.WriteLine(((foo)o).i)
```

> C# is a statically typed (typed safe) language and only allows type
>   safe operations and as there is no `public` member `i` of class
>   `object` therefore it is not allowed by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

`o` is of type object which can hold `object` of any type but instance of object can not access the attributes of `assigned` class object.

Type casting to its respective class make the public members accessible like this.

```
Console.WriteLine(((foo)o).i)
```